# How to open a web page inside an iOS app with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, url, cordova

I want to have only one view in my iOS phonegap app.

This view will be a web page.

How can i load this only view with a specific url?

I suppose you do that through javascript and if yes how?

*I am not an html/javascript scripter , i only develop native iOS applications , but i need to test something with phonegap.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**d0nparalias**,

1. If you want to load main(Cordova's) `index.html` from remote server, edit `config.xml` file and change
   `<content src="index.html" />`

   to
   `<content src="http://192.168.1.4:8080/www/index.html" />`
   for example. And it will load `index.html` from web server located on 192.168.1.4.
2. If you want to open a website right after loading your app, you can use [InAppBrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) as you have already noticed.
   `window.open(url, target, options);`
   Here you have options for `target` (according to Cordova docs 2.5.0):

   2.1. `_self` and you'll get something like
   [image]
   Note, that you don't have any controls to return to your `index.html` in this case.

   2.2. `_blank` — presents modal view controller with dismiss button
   [image]

   2.3. `_system` — opens in Safari.app
   [image]

For more information visit [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) and [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser).

Hope it helps.
BR.
Eugene

Comment: One of the best answers , i ve ever seen. Thank you so much Eugene.

Comment: One more question that just thought. Now that i am changing my source how will i load the pushnotification.js that i am using to use pushnotifications? I mean before , i was adding a script reference like this : <script src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>  to my index.html. Now that i dont load it , how will i load the pushnotifications?

Comment: I guess i have to use the 2.1 that you are saying. Can you please give me an example of that? I am not sure how to implement it , in my code.

Comment: Check this if u have time please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343647/using-phonegap-cordova-on-ios-with-external-url

Comment: Hi @dymv ! I have a question , Can I load a website that show video as streaming ? for example Can i show a video from youtube ?

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap which is now called Apache Cordova on iOS will only let you use a file URL by default.  This means you have to load a local .html file.  If you want to open a remote page with an http:// URL, you'll need to add custom native code to tell the WebView to load a remote URL.

Comment: omg really? And i started working with phonegap only to see how it would work on loading a remote url. You are a 100% positive that you cant load a webview on it? I mean on javascript that you run , if you "call" an url what will happen? It will open in safari?

Comment: Are you sure man? Cause i am reading now on the documentation about in app browser " The InAppBrowser is a web-browser that is shown in your app when you use the window.open call. "