# Open a web page inside an Windows app with Cordova?

Tags: windows, web-services, cordova

I'm trying to use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15319156/753878) to open web page inside may Cordova Windows application by changing:

```
  <content src="index.html" />
```

with

```
 <content src="http://http://192.168.8.33:8080/war/index.htm" />
```

but for for some reason I get this big error in compilation:

```
    Platform      : anycpu
C:\windowsProject\test1\platforms\windows\build\windows80\debug\anycpu\AppxMani
fest.xml(24,41): error APPX1404: File content does not conform to specified sch
ema. The 'StartPage' attribute is invalid - The value 'www/http://192.168.8.33:
8080/war/index.html' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schema
s.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest:ST_FileName' - The Pattern constraint failed
. [C:\windowsProject\test1\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows80.jsproj]
```

I'm using Cordova 4.3.0 and my target paltform is Windows

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No not yet, apparently I'm the only one who have this problem

Comment: i solved it by redirecting to my webpage from a custom function in index.html