# using inappbrowser to convert website to mobile app without showing the link of the website

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am using phonegap to be able to have my website (that is already hosted in shared hosting server) and has responsive web design. I have tried the solution provided in posted question:

1. typing my website link in src, that has been done successfully as the index page is loaded and no website link shown in the app, but once the user click on any button (which basically go to other website pages) it will open it inside the app but the link of the webpage is shown, you can see the screenshout I took from my mobile (android).

```html
<content src="http://192.168.1.4:8080/www/index.html" />
```

I have followed the same instruction in the answer and set the target to _self in the following:

```html
indow.open(url, target, options);
```

but it still show the link of the site.

Thanks
[image: screenshot of the app running in android device]

Comment: it is window.open(url, target, options); I didn't copy it above properly, and the answer that I am following for my issue is  from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298737/how-to-open-a-web-page-inside-an-ios-app-with-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figure out this issue, Actually I need to set the location = no and the  link will not be shown